# How to get Selected Row Contents from DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

How to get Selected Row Contents from DataGridView in C#

I have a DataGridView with 9 columns. And I fill these columns from a Stdn_Registration_tbl (table) that has 20 columns (I mean I picked only specific columns for GridView). 
Now I want when somebody clicks Right Mouse button on a Selected Row, it popups a ContextMenuStrip.

```
if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(searchStdn_dtGv, e.Location);
            }
```

And after clicking **View** (Context Menu Item) it shows all the data from Stdn_Registration_tbl in another form (form2).

Answer (score 0):

Pass a DataGridViewRow from Form1 to Form2:

```
//In Form1
DataGridViewRow r = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.row = r;
f.ShowDialog();

//In Form2
public DataGridViewRow row;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  label1.text = row.cell[0].ToString();
  .
  .
  .
  label9.text = row.cell[8].ToString();
}
```